# Get all sites in site collection without getting all lists?

Tags: sharepoint

I saw the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx to get all sites and list and I am binding it to a dropdown, it works but I also get all the lists for each site so the site name appears many times in the dropdown which I don't want.

My code is:

```
private void getSites()
{
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

    for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++)
    {
        using (SPWeb oWebsite = collWebsite[i])
        {
            SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

            for (int j = 0; j < collList.Count; j++)
            {
                ddlParentSite.Items.Add(new ListItem(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(collWebsite[i].Title)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get sites only and not their lists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No offence peter but did you put any effort at all into trying to understand what that code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment out the code to add lists. See below:

```
private void getSites()
{
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

    for (int i = 0; i < collWebsite.Count; i++)
    {
       ddlParentSite.Items.Add(new ListItem(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(collWebsite[i].Title)));
    }
}
```

Comment: A dispose or using should be used with the AllWebs[] indexer. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_130